# Repeating if else statement

Tags: java

Sorry for asking stupid question but I'm out of idea.
I wish to repeat the if else statement until get the valid input then proceed to ask next question.
can anyone tell me what's wrong?
The code itself didnt have any problem (it can run) but it only display "Error" and "please re-enter the answer" then proceed to next part already without asking the "day" again.
Thanks in advance

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Day; // The user’s name.
        TextIO.put("This program is to tell you what to eat for today.");
        TextIO.put("\nBefore it starts, can you tell me what's the day today?");

        Day = TextIO.getln();{

        if (Day.equals("Monday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Tuesday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Oranges");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Wednesday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Strawberries");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Thursday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Lemons");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Friday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Bananas");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Saturday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Apples");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Sunday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Grass");
        }

        else if (Day.equals(false))
        {System.out.print("Error");
        System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer");
        Day = TextIO.getln();

        }
```

Comment: What is the value you are giving to `Day`?

Comment: if `Day` is string how can you compare it with boolean `if (Day.equals(false))`?

Comment: You should a) use a switch statement (Java 7 and higher). Defining constants and/or enums for week days will help you, too.

Comment: Little note on comments, they get out of date fast: `String Day; // The user’s name.`

Comment: @JonK with autoboxing, false will become a `Boolean`. `day.equals("false")` is **very, very** different to `day.equals(Boolean.valueOf(false))`. If you want to see it, test `"false".equals("false")` vs  `"false".equals(false)`

Comment: You could also use a `HashMap` to map from a day to food to eat.

Comment: As an aside, the Java convention is that variables are in camelCase unless they're constants, so `Day` should be `day`.

Comment: @SJuan76 Out of curiosity, would it not be `String.valueOf(false)` instead?

Comment: @JonK `false` is a boolean primitive. Autoboxing it produces a `Boolean` instance. `String.valueOf()` returns a `String`. QED, the autoboxing cannot be done by `String.valueOf`. Of course, going to the previous expression, if you do: `"false".equals(String.valueOf(false))` will return `true`, but that is not what happens in autoboxing.

Comment: @SJuan76 Makes sense, thanks for sating my curiosity

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use loops

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Day; // The user’s name.
        TextIO.put("This program is to tell you what to eat for today.");
        TextIO.put("\nBefore it starts, can you tell me what's the day today?");

        do
        {
        Day = TextIO.getln();

        if (Day.equals("Monday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Tuesday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Oranges");
            break;
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Wednesday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Strawberries");
            break;
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Thursday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Lemons");
            break;
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Friday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Bananas");
            break;
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Saturday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Apples");
            break;
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Sunday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Grass");
            break;
        }

        else if (Day.equals(false))
        {System.out.print("Error");
        System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer");
        }
     }while(true);
 }
```

Comment: there is no exit condition. this is an infitnite loop. this may confuse the OP more than help him/her

Comment: Sorry Mr.Harshit
I try to copy paste the code to understand it but it gives me 
Syntax Error:insert "while (expression)" to complete do statement

Comment: Sorry @Harshit I try to copy paste the code to understand it but it gives me syntax error. Insert"while (expresssion)" to complete do statement

Comment: @Harshit Thanks a lot, the loop itself works, (Now i try to understand it how it works) , However I still have 1 question,  else if (Day.equals(false))
        {System.out.print("Error");
        System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer");
        }
     }while(true);

It doesn't display both sentence, I've try to remove the {} and it only show sentence 2 which is Please reenter the answer. However, if i delete the sentence 1 , sentence 2 wont show out

Comment: @Harshit never mind, I found the solution already , need to close the statement else if (Day.equals(false));

Comment: @SimonAng, Glad to know you finally got the solution. So, if you got the solution and if my answer helped you then mark it as answer.

Comment: Note to everybody: this code style is **AWFUL**. Abuse of `break` without need usually leads to readibility and maintenaince issues, as it makes more difficult to understand the logic behind continuing in the loop or exiting it. Note the high number of downvotes.

Comment: @Harshit this code IS awful. Dont use multiple if but switch instead. And what happens if the input text isn't a day ??

Comment: Do not get into defensive mode, because my comments are not mean to be offensive. They are meant to signal the problems with your code to you (also, the "Day.equals(false)" is meaningless) and, if you fail to fix it, to avoid other unexperienced people from repeating your mistakes. The fact that your code is far from perfect only means that you lack experience; my code when I began programming was far worse than this but I listened and searched for advice on how to comment it (which is something you can hardly you when you get into defensive mode).

Answer (score 2):

Better use a switch statement for multiple if:

```
boolean error=false;
    do{
        error=false;
        String day="";
        switch (day) {
        case "Monday":
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
            break;
        case "Tuesday":
            System.out.print("Eat Oranges");
            break;
            .
            .
            .
        default:
            System.out.print("Error");
            System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer");
            error=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    while(error)
```

Comment: ok I will try to figure it out how it runs :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should look `while` or `do-while` in `Java`.

You can get the idea from following example..

```
boolean status = true;   
String input = "";
while (status) {
 System.out.println("your input\n");
 input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
 if (input.equals("valid")) {
    System.out.println("valid input");
    status = false;
 } else {
    // not a valid input
    System.out.println("Please re-try");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String day = TextIO.getln();
List<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"));
while (!daysOfWeek.contains(day)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    day = TextIO.getln();
}
... continue with program after valid input ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a TextIO class from here : http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/source/

Then I edited your code so that it looked like this...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Day; // The user’s name.
        TextIO.put("This program is to tell you what to eat for today.");
        TextIO.put("\nBefore it starts, can you tell me what's the day today?");

        Day = TextIO.getln();

        if (Day.equals("Monday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Tuesday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Oranges");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Wednesday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Strawberries");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Thursday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Lemons");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Friday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Bananas");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Saturday")){
        System.out.print("Eat Apples");
        }
        else if (Day.equals("Sunday")){
            System.out.print("Eat Grass");
        }
        else if (Day.equals(false))
        {System.out.print("Error");
        System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer");
        Day = TextIO.getln();

        }
}

}
```

Finally I ran this code and got this..

```
$ java Test
This program is to tell you what to eat for today.
Before it starts, can you tell me what's the day today?Monday
Eat Chocolates
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way to use Java OOD Concepts and create a recursive method for this.and switch statement is more suitable than a if else ladder.
u can get a more better idea about recursive methods in java by following [1].
Simply your program can be change as:

```
    public class Test {


        public Test() {

        }


        public void getInput() {
             String Day; // The user’s name.
                TextIO.put("This program is to tell you what to eat for today.");
                TextIO.put("\nBefore it starts, can you tell me what's the day today?");
         String day=TextIO.getln();
            switch (day) {
            case "Monday":
                System.out.print("Eat Chocolates");
                break;
            case "Tuesday":
                System.out.print("Eat Oranges");
                break;
                .
                .
                .
            default:
                System.out.print("Error");
                System.out.print("\nPlease re-eneter the answer");
               getInput();
            }
            }



        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Test test = new Test();
                test.getInput();
         }
   }
```

[1]. http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Really misguided answer. This is a clear case of a iterative logic. Making it recursive only makes it more complicated, slightly slower and introduces the possibility of stackoverflows, for no gain at all. Recursion has it uses but this is not one of them.